# Invalid template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I'm struggling with templates ! Consider the following code:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Sequence {};

template<unsigned N> struct B {
  template<unsigned P> struct C {
    typedef int type;
  };
};
```

Then this is perfectly correct:

```
template<unsigned... Is>
struct Loop2 {
  typedef Sequence< typename B<5>::C<Is>::type... > type;
};

Loop2<3,1> l;
```

Therefore I can't understand why this templated version:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct Loop3 {
  typedef Sequence< typename B<N>::C<Is>::type... > type;
};
```

isn't accepted by the compiler. It raise the following error:

```
essai.cpp:29:51: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   typedef Sequence< typename B<N>::C<Is>::type... > type;
```

For the information I got this with

```
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]
```

Thanks for any help !

By the way: any suggestion for a better title is welcome !

Comment: *"Therefore I can't understand why this templated version [..] isn't accepted by the compiler"* Because there could be a `template<> struct B<4> { int C; };`, i.e., that `C` is a template isn't obvious to the compiler w/o a specific specialization of `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As B is not a specific type anymore, you need to flag C with the `template` keyword as it is depenend on the value of N. Using the follwing code should work:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct Loop3 {
  typedef Sequence< typename B<N>::template C<Is>::type... > type;
};
```

Comment: You seems to be right but I don't understand what you mean by "B is not a specific type anymore". Can you clarify or point to a reference ?

Comment: With B<5> in Loop2 we have instantiated a type from a template, i.e. the compiler is given a specific type whereas in the B<N> situation we still have a template that depends on how N will be choosen "some time later" and may vary between usages of Loop3.

Comment: @hivert: Stated in a different way: since `B<N>` is *dependent* on the template arguments, you need to qualify any nested class/template with the `typename`/`template` keywords

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for those explanations !